# If bimodules are important, why not bi-vector spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, modules

Bi-modules are a high profile math concept in abstract algebra. Why aren't bi-vector spaces not so common? I don't see them on the [wikipedia article about vector space,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) and they yield [not many results on google.](https://www.google.com.ar/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bi%20vector%20space&*)

My idea: A $(K_1,K_2)$ Vector space $V$ would be the analogous definition of [bimodule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimodule) changing module for vector space and field for ring: $V$ is a $K_1$ vector space to the left (wich actually is the same as just "vector space" since fields are conmutative) is also a $K_2$ vector space to the right.

Compatibility: $k_1*(v*k_2)=(k_1*v)*k_2$, with $k_1 \in K_1$, $k_2 \in K_2$, $v \in V$.

Comment: Well, a bi-vector space *is* a bimodule.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks! That's true according to my definition of bi-vector space, however it would be nice to see that in other references, to see if someone else uses it! Also, I answer this to you: a field is a ring, but still we need to study fields.

Comment: A vector space is a special case of a module. Vector spaces are modules over fields (or division rings).

Comment: Note that fields are commutative, so it doesn't really matter wether scalar multiplication happens on the right or left.

Comment: @MattSamuel You don't understand my complain about your last comment, I believe. What you are saying is totally true, but even if vector spaces are special cases of modules, we need to study them, that's why they write books and articles about them, since they have new properties, because more axioms are allowed, they obbey more rules.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the case of vector spaces, it's not particularly natural here to restrict attention to fields for bimodules. As paul garrett says, the basic problem is that if $M$ is a $(K_1, K_2)$-bimodule over a field $k$, where $K_1, K_2$ are both fields, then equivalently $M$ is a $K_1 \otimes_k K_2$-module, and $K_1 \otimes_k K_2$ need not be a field.

For a simple example, if $k = \mathbb{R}$ and $K_1 = K_2 = \mathbb{C}$, then

$$\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}.$$

So in the nice cases, instead of a field you get a finite direct product of fields (e.g. if $K_1, K_2$ are both finite separable extensions of $k$), which is not too bad. What this means is that every $(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{C})$-bimodule over $\mathbb{R}$ is a direct sum of copies of two simple bimodules, one given by $\mathbb{C}$ with the obvious bimodule structure and one given by $\mathbb{C}$ where one of the multiplications has been "twisted" by complex conjugation.

But worse things can happen: if $k = \mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and $K_1 = K_2 = k[x]/(x^p - t)$, then

$$K_1 \otimes_k K_2 \cong K_1[x]/(x - \sqrt[p]{t})^p$$

which has a nontrivial nilpotent, and in particular which is not semisimple.

Answer (score 1):

I do think there is some non-trivial content here: even with commutative rings with identity, an $R,S$-bimodule is an $R\otimes S$-module (and without commutativity, then one ring has to be replaced by its *opposite*).

Even when both $R,S$ are algebras over a common field $k$, and the tensor product is over $k$, non-trivial things can happen. E.g., even when $R,S$ are fields, the tensor product is not a field unless $R,S$ are "linearly disjoint", or some other hypothesis. So $R,S$-bimodules have more structure than just "vectorspace" over the common under-field $k$.

Comment: "some non trivial content" what do you refer to? the question or the sentence following you wrote? Thanks , i want to understand your contribution!

Comment: I think there is non-trivial content to the question itself.